# What does saying "X" mean in the faction chat?

Tags: terminology, albion-online

I see many people "x" in the chat, but I cannot find a clear answer to what it means. Asking in the chat also does not give me any answers.

[image: People saying "x" in chat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you want a party invite.

x [zone] means you're looking for a party invite for that specific zone.

X by itself can also be used to express doubt, similarly to "Press F to show your respects", but I don't think this is common in Albion Online.